# Implement Boolean function using only 4x1 multiplexer considering A and D as input and B,C as selection values

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra, function

F(A,B,C,D) = Σm(0,1,3,4,6,7,11,12,14,15)

How do I use A and D as input and use only 2 selection lines for a 4 variable function?

Comment: I think it would take three of these parts to provide this function

Comment: Very strong smell of homework off this on. No smell of attempted solution. -1.

Comment: @transistor I got it in my exam and I think I got it wrong. Just wanted to know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very straight forward if you start by writing down a truth table. In the 16 count there are two sets of 8 corresponding to BC values (00,01,10, and 11). Pull these values out into their own truth tables and you see an interesting pattern for the values of A and D.

The value (BC) 00 corresponds to NOT A

The value (BC) 01 corresponds to  D

The value (BC) 10 corresponds to NOT D

The value (BC) 11 corresponds to  HIGH
[image]